# Counting all documents in a FaunaDB collection

Tags: faunadb

Is there a way to count all documents in a collection in FaunaDB?

Say I have a `users` collection and I have defined an `all_users` index. What is the best way to count all documents in the `users` collection in the database?

### Update: expanding on @Keston's answer below

1. The `all_users` index is no longer needed. Fauna now automatically maintains a built-in default index for each collection, and you can access it via `Documents(Collection('<collection>'))`.
2. You can count all users like so:

```
Count(Documents(Collection('users')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now faunadb offers the count() function in the most recent release which is another option to maintaining an aggregate

https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/count

Comment: Thanks for the update @Keston. It looks like `count()` is for `Array`, `Set` or `Page`, so not sure if it would work for all documents in a collection? I'd have to try it out though, as I haven't used Fauna in a while. Good to see new features added.

Comment: You can count the all_users index, any index you count will return everything in the index. or you can filter an index and count that. Im pretty sure an index falls under the set category. That is an index is a set

Comment: You can indeed count using an index, but you must wrap it in `Match` first (e.g., `Count(Match(Index('all_users')))`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to maintain your own aggregate in transaction with your data updates, so update a counter document when you write your new users. I wrote a blog post about how to do that here: https://blog.fauna.com/using-acid-transactions-to-combine-queries-and-ensure-integrity (See the last example)